# Wordpress post editor sidebar remove

Tags: wordpress, post, text

Is there a way to remove the sidebar column from the textarea in the post editor in wordpress?
[image: Text editor]

Comment: I've never seen that before in any of my WordPress installs, my guess is that theme or a plugin has some added code that is causing that. Does that sidebar do anything? Can you type into it?

Comment: Me too i have never seen that before. No i cannot type in that area. I am using Newspaper 7 theme

Comment: This appears to be related to the post template. I think they are trying to show you what the post will look like when a sidebar is present so you can get a rough idea of how things will break. They have [samples of this "feature" on their site](http://forum.tagdiv.com/post-formats-for-tinymce/) (scroll to the bottom). You might be able to switch the template/layout, otherwise you'd have to hack the theme, probably, to disable this.

Comment: thank you i will have to check the code of the template in order to disable it